# Share mouse and keyboard between multiple androids

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I'm new to android but I have an application in mind that I'm willing to work long for: setting up three or four android tablets upright, as if I were looking at a four-monitor desktop pc, and use one bluetooth mouse and keyboard between the four of them.

Where should I start. I'm sure that some combination of android packages must allow me to do this... :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it isnt possible, because Bluetooth protocol currently allows just one-to-one connection. You have to create "master" device which next share keyboard and mouse throw diffrent protocol, eg. WiFi.
But I still do not see any use for this :)